# Cannot detect cyclic data in an SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite, I have a suspected case of recursive data that has cycle - in other words, a child node is also its own grandparent. The symptom, of course, is an infinite loop

I know how Oracle and Postgresql handle cyclic data; but have not found any method to do so with SQLite. Below is an example of data with a cycle. If you remove the last "row" in the dataset table, it will work. As written, it goes into an infinite loop.

```
with DataSet as
(
  select  'A' as node, null as parent union all
  select  'B' as node, 'A' as parent union all
  select  'C' as node, 'B' as parent union all
  select  'D' as node, 'C' as parent union all
  select  'A' as node, 'D' as parent
),
Hierarchy( node, parent, level, path )
as
(
  select  DataSet.node,
          DataSet.parent,
          1 as level,
          '/' || DataSet.node as path
  from     DataSet
  where    DataSet.parent is null

  union all
  select  DataSet.node,
          DataSet.parent,
          Hierarchy.level + 1 as level,
          Hierarchy.path || '/' || DataSet.node as path
  from    Hierarchy
  join    DataSet
  on      DataSet.parent = Hierarchy.node
)
select    *
from      Hierarchy

order by  path
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `level`, you could use UNION to ignore the duplicates.

Otherwise, there is no easy way to compare 'old' rows.
You could add a sufficiently large LIMIT to prevent the loop from becoming infinite, but then it is not always possible to remove duplicates.

Comment: Your approach doesn't work since the query is in a loop and can't finish in order to do the dup removal. I did try it to be sure.

Comment: Please note the first three words of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop (pun intended) on this, I finally figured out a method that works. Plus I even added a column to show the rows where a cyclic condition exists. This solution includes: level (depth) number, parent, child, path (root to node/leaf), and a zero or one for detection of a cycle. You can paste the SQL below into the sqlite3 prompt and it will display:

```
level   parent   node     path          cyclic_flag  
------  -------  -------  ------------  ------------  
0       A        B        /A/B          0  
1       B        C        /A/B/C        0  
2       C        D        /A/B/C/D      0  
3       D        A        /A/B/C/D/A    1  
sqlite>
```

Finally, here is the SQL that shows the method. The only tricky part is the use of counting substrings in the path (the next node being the substring counted).

with dataset as
(
  select  'A' as parent, 'B' as node union all
  select  'B' as parent, 'C' as node  union all
  select  'C' as parent, 'D' as node
  union all select  'D' as parent, 'A' as node
),
hierarchy( level, parent, node, path, cyclic_flag )
as
(
  select  0 as level,
          dataset.parent,
          dataset.node,
          '/' || dataset.parent || '/' || dataset.node as path,
          0 as cyclic_flag
  from     dataset
  where    dataset.parent = 'A'

union all
  select
          hierarchy.level + 1 as level,
          dataset.parent,
          dataset.node,
          hierarchy.path || '/' || dataset.node as path,
          case
          when
          (length(path||dataset.node) - length(replace(path|| dataset.node,dataset.node,'')))/length(dataset.node) = 1
          then 0
          else 1
          end as cyclic_flag
  from    hierarchy
  inner join dataset
  on      dataset.parent =  hierarchy.node
  where (length(path) -   length(replace(path,hierarchy.node,'')))/length(hierarchy.node) < 2
)
select    *
from       hierarchy

order by  path
;